# fast way to handle a 2D array as grouped by values in a 2nd 2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to python and I'm trying to understand how to process these arrays without looping through them iteratively, which has proven much too slow.

I have two arrays, both of them are the same shape '(480, 640)', called 'heights' and `sectors` You may imagine I have a 480x640 plot of wheat heads, each with a given height, where the plot is split into 'sectors'.

Say I want to calculate the average height of wheat in each sector, and check the height of each wheat head compared to the average height of wheat in its respective sector. I can do this iteratively with for loops, but I'm looking for a way to do it much faster.

'heights' is an array of floats that look like:

```
[[1.343  2.456  2.345...  3.123  1.456  2.765]
 [2.445  3.556  3.778 ... 3 667  2.112  2 752]
 [2.567  3.567  1.334...  3.778  1.228  3.550]
...
 [3.112  1.001  1.332...  2.334  2.445  1 220]
 [2.754  1.457  1.754...  1.786  2.789  3.991]
 [1.003  2.009  2.354...  1.112  3.449  3.993]]
```

and 'sectors' is an array of ints this looks something like this. *(The full array has up to 20 sectors laud out sort of like the flag of Japan, where each sun ray has its own number, as do the sun and a surrounding border, but the arrangement of the sectors is not really important to the problem)*:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 0.]
 [0. 2. 1. ... 1. 2. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 3. 1. ... 1. 2. 0.]
 [0. 3. 3. ... 2. 2. 0.]
 [0. 3. 3. ... 4. 4. 0.]]
```

So now if I were to overlay the two arrays, each head of wheat would be associated with its own sector number based on where it lies on the array. There could be anywhere from around 4000 to 9000 heads of wheat in each sector

What I want to do is to find the average of all heights within each sector, as fast as possible.

Subsequently, I want to compare each value in 'heights' against its respective sector value.

and lastly, I want to use the comparisons to create a new array *(in the example below, I create a black and white image mask, but that's not important to the problem)*

I tried doing it iteratively with for loops, like this:

```
def enumerate2D(array1, array2):
    assert array1.shape == array2.shape, "Error - dimensions."
    for indexes, data in np.ndenumerate(array1):
        yield indexes, data, array2[indexes]


#create container to eventually hold averages for each sector
comparebins = np.zeros(numberofSectors)

#container for tallying how many pixels lie in each sector
inEach = np.zeros(numberofSectors,int)          

# find sum of heights in each sector
for index, sector, height in enumerate2D(sectors, heights):
    comparebins[sector] = comparebins[sector] + height
    inEach[sector] += 1

#average each sector 
comparebins  = comparebins / inEach  


# Now that I have the averages, I have to run through heights again,
# applying a conditional and using indices to write each pixel of a mask

#create an image mask
maskoid = np.zeros((480, 640))

#now check each height value again
for index, sector, height in enumerate2D(sectors, heights): 
    if abs(height - comparebins[sector]) > someThreshold:
        maskoid2[index] = 255
```

This type of method works, but it takes much too long. I'm working with video, so I need to be able to do this 30 times per second. I can shring my arrays to perhaps 30% of their current size for the sake of speed, but with this iterative approach it still took too long with arrays 25% this size.

It seems like I should be able to use some sort of fast "vectorized" operations with pandas or numpy. I tried using this a method that uses pandas and [groupby](http://esantorella.com/2016/06/16/groupby/)

But I could not for the life of me figure out how to create the `DataFrame` object using my two arrays. Am I on the right track? This seems like it should be easier, but I'm not used to python arrays, especially indexing, slicing, axes, and so forth.

Comment: Can you please define all variables and functions with some representative data? I.e. `numSectors`, `enumerate2D`, `comparebins1`, `statbins` and others are all undefined.

Comment: can you elaborate : "What I really want to do is to find the average angs value and mags value within each sector, for each frame, as fast as possible."?  whats sector? is it [patch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_meaning_of_kernels_image_patch_and_window_in_image_processing/amp&ved=2ahUKEwinpfqtpM3jAhUIFpoKHdj9CxsQFjALegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3tYn1UW58NDpSHjwWjAxBg&ampcf=1)?

Comment: Thanks guys, I think my original explanation was too obtuse, so I've totally overhauled the way I framed the question. I'm hoping if it's not too much trouble you could take another look. It's greatly appreciated.